как добавить интервал нажатия и сделать рандом?
взял отсюда тыкни
суть: при нажатии на кнопку, мне выдает разные заранее прописанные div с id от page0 до page2, мне нужно добавить интервал чтобы следующее нажатие происходило не сразу, а допустим после 5 секунд, так же чтобы при перезагрузке сайта не давало первоначальный div с id page0 а допустим любой другой div с id от page0 до page2
$('.close').click(function() {
$('.screenpage:visible').hide().siblings().eq(Math.floor(Math.random() * 3)).show();
});


запоминаете время нажатия. При  новом нажатии сравниваете, если меньше 5 сек прошло, то сразу на выход

У вас тут 2 вопроса. Выберите один. Так же у вас в теге javascript,  а код приведен на jquery

два вопроса запрещено создавать? просто не хочу два вопроса отдельно создавать
